# Is there a way to open a page in an iframe from the previous tab?

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I host cooking recipes, on the index of the site there is a "recent dishes" button that you can click to view my most recent dish. The problem arises when you factor in that my most recent dish is designed to be viewed inside an Iframe in a "dish index". The dish index has a sidebar with important information that I would like to not have to implement a javascript solution for.

In summary, is there a way to format a link to open the index page, and then open the iframe inside the page?

just for extra clarification, as it seems there are a bunch of questions asking how to do a similar sounding thing.

click link.

link open.

Iframe inside of link opens to a specific page, separate from the default.

[Here](https://melonking.net/melon.html) is a website that has the behavior that I'm looking for, but they're using Framesets and frames which were deprecated in html4 i believe. Please note that the sidebar does not refresh/load when a link is clicked, but the url does.

I've been googling for about 15 minutes now and have not found a solution, other than the javascript one.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to have a menu and once a link inside this menu has been clicked you want to load different pages. If that is correct then make the menu the main page and then change `frame src` for different pages. You use `target` in the link to target the `iframe`
A short example can be found below

```
<a href="page1.html" target="myIframe"> Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" target="myIframe"> Page 2</a>

<iframe src="Page1.html" name="myIframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: sorry i was pretty tired when i wrote this,(still kinda am, have a bit of insomnia) i have an iframe that is designed to be viewed in an index page. i want to open that index page and then open the iframe in the index page to a specific recipe, preferably through a link. the reason i want to do this is because i have a sidebar beside all recipes that provides important info and i would rather not have that side menu refresh every time someone clicked a new recipe. thank you for your help.